# In angular i want to show/hide certain elements depending on routerlinks?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have 6 URL's.

case 1 : For 3 URL's visible div name "box-A" and hide "box-B"

case 2 : For other 3 URL's visible div name "box-B" and hide "box-A"

How to write conditions according to the routerLinks. I'm using angular version 8. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(private router: Router){
console.log(router.url);

router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(event => 
       {
          this.currentRoute = event.url;         
       });
}
```

You can do ***ngIf** on the basis of the **this.currentRoute** property in your HTML. If you don't wanted to remove div completely from your DOM, you can also use **[hidden]** instead of ***ngIf**.

Comment: @kunal thanks! Is any div condition in html?

Comment: I didn't got your question @Amol

Comment: i have different url's mentioned in my route.module.ts, & i have 2 header in header.component.html
When some url's when opened a inside header A div is visible header B div is hide.

Comment: can you send me your code what so far have you tried please. So I can take a look.

Comment: @kunal please look at demo code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tjpymx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

// in your component.ts :

```
public canShowBoxA = false;
public canShowBoxB = false;
constructor(private router: Route) {
    this.router.events.subscribe( (val: any) => {
      this.activateDiv(this.router.url);
    });
  }

activateDiv(url: string) {
 // check url value to update canShowBoxA and canShowBoxB 
}
```

// in your component.html

```
<div *ngIf="canShowBoxB">             
 Box B
</div>

<div *ngIf="canShowBoxA">             
Box A
</div>
```